# Sum column from several files on Linux Command line

Tags: linux, bash

I have many tab-delimited files with lines in the following format:

```
...
some_str\tsome_str\tsome_str\tsome_str\tsome_int
some_str\tsome_str\tsome_str\tsome_str\tsome_int
...
```

The first four columns are the same in all of them, but the last column varies across files. Is there an easy way to create one file in bash where the first four columns are the same, and the last column is the sum of all files' last column? Like:

```
...
some_str\tsome_str\tsome_str\tsome_str\tsum_of_that_value_in_all_files
some_str\tsome_str\tsome_str\tsome_str\tsum_of_that_value_in_all_files
...
```

I am looking for a simple one liner in bash if possible.

Comment: What is the "Linux Command line"? Is it `bash`? `dash`? `zsh`? a Python script? something else? You should clarify what kind of code you're looking for as the answers could vary quite widely.

Comment: Thanks for the input, edited the question!

Answer (score 2):

yes, awk can do it:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]+=$5}
   END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' *.tsv (or other patterns for all your files)
```

The command was not tested, but I think it should go. If you want to save the result to other file, just add `> newFile` at the end.

Comment: Thank you! Will try immediately!

Comment: why not simply awk -F'\t' '{a+=$5}END{print $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS a}' file*

Comment: @ctac_ that will only work if there is only one  (same) key in all the files.

Comment: @karakfa yes but it's this way I understand the question.The first four columns are the same in all of them, but the last column varies across files

Comment: @ctac_ check the example, there are two input lines and two output lines. yours will be the grand sum of all.

Comment: @karakfa yes it seems you are right, like we say in french,we must read between the lines.

Answer (score 1):

similar `awk` but without fixing the number of columns

```
$ awk '    {k=$NF; sub(k"$",""); sum[$0]+=k} 
       END {for(k in sum) print k,sum[k]}' files
```

the order of the records may not be preserved, but is not affected by the order of keys in any of the files either.